# Give my application of Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid app, I would like to give "codes" for some users to download it for free. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send your "paid app" to some of your users for free, but you don't want it to be distributed out, right?

The best straightforward and non-technical approach is to buy google play gift card by yourself and send them to your selected users.

If you insist on doing this in a technical way, there is no better solution for this case if your application only has a solo paid version on play store. If you have a free version which requires user to buy a premium key or pay through in-app billing to get the paid version, you can do it this way:

1. Collect google account name of all the users that you want to give the chance for free promotion
2. Upload a new free version to google play store, in this version, your app will check the google account name of the device (you can use a db file if the number is huge), if it is in the name list, the device can get the premium promotion for free.

This is just a small trick. And it even works if you only have a solo paid version on google playstore. You can send out your application, which will check the account name before it performs the job. But this is not a good idea since user cannot upgrade your app via google play in this way.

Comment: Thanks! …-". If you have a free version which requires user to buy a premium key or pay through in-app billing to get the paid version, you can do it this way:…" Perfect!

Comment: Aha, thanks for such a big praise. I have this idea because I also have considered this situation seriously before. I'd be happier if you up vote this answer :) LOL